# Use variable ouside of scope in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, scope, global-variables

Here I have a small snippet which has a variable num_cpu under a if condition, i am not able to access it outside the if condition tag. How do i solve this?

How do i make the num_cpu global so that i can use it multiple times outside the for loop?

```
    <xsl:for-each select="t:container">
        <xsl:if test="@name = 'cpu'">
            <xsl:variable name="num_cpu" select="t:leaf/t:value/@value"/>
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:value-of select="$num_cpu"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

To define a global variable, place the `<xsl:variable>` element as a child of the root stylesheet element.

In addition to answer the question in the comment. How to change the value in the if condition:
XSLT is not an imperative programming language where you can change the value of a variable.

If you want to pass a value from one template to another then you can use a parameter e.g.

Code Snippet

```
<xsl:template match="foo">

  <xsl:apply-templates select="bar">

    <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="100"/>

  </xsl:apply-templates>

</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="bar">

  <xsl:param name="pos"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply,
Even if i declare the variable under root stylesheet the value being assigned to it under if condition is not accessible outside if condition, how do i handle that?

Comment: You aren't assigning a value to the variable in the if condition, you are declaring a completely new variable that happens to have the same name.